# Can't go back after clicking on a Google Maps link

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova

In my app, coded with Cordova, there are links like:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London,+GB">Show map for London</a>
```

When clicking on them, Google Maps opens and shows the correct address. The problem is that I can't go back to my app by tapping on the back button.

I think it's because I'm overwriting the `backbutton` event listener. In fact, If I comment out the following line:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", historyBack, true);
```

Everything works fine. The thing is that I obviously want to call my custom `historyBack()` function when pressing the back button. Even if the `historyBack()` function only contains `alert("test");` it doesn't fire when pressing the back button while viewing the map.

Is there any workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, change the address to:

```
<a href="geo:0,0?q=London,+GB" target="_blank">Show map for London</a>
```

This will open the actual Google Maps app (or any other app of your choice), instead of showing the map inside your app.

Answer (score -1):

In the code where you override the back button, add super.onBackPressed();