# Go back after open google map by href in Android App

Tags: android, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, back-button

In my Android App, I have a link that opens a Google Maps URL to show the user how to go to from its location to a certain place. The problem, is that the link opens over my App and I can't go back to it pressing the phone's back shortcut.

In the `href` attribute of my `<a>`, im using this URL:

> http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr={{item.latitude}},{{item.longitude}}&ll=

I'm using Ionic and AngularJS.

I have tried this solution: [Can't go back after clicking on a Google Maps link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461541/cant-go-back-after-clicking-on-a-google-maps-link), but i don't know how to make the same query in the above url using the `geo:` protocol.

Someone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `geo: protocol` Please try following code:

`href="geo:<lat>,<long>?q=<lat>,<long>(Label+Name)">Locate</a>`

Change the `lat` and `long` as you wish.

For more details, please refer to [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps).